# How to solve ComPtr Access Violation Error?

Tags: c++

I am not extremely proficient with ComPtr in C++ WinRT. I understand the basics concepts, but haven't mastered all of its functionality.

I am porting the [How to save Direct2D content to an image file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/save-direct2d-content-to-an-image-file) example from C++ W32 to C++ WinRT. I have successfully used `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` to create the D2D objects for rendering the D2D content. I have also successfully ported the first sections from the example.

However, I have hit an impasse with the following code:

```cpp
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IWICBitmapEncoder> wicBitmapEncoder;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> wicFactory;
wicFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, NULL, &wicBitmapEncoder);
```

The `CreateEncoder()` call throws an exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6A8BF1118 in C++WRT_D2D_ScreenClearApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Both `WicFactory` and `&wicBitmap` point to `0x00000000` (`nullptr`). To me, this says I need to initialize the two `ComPtr` objects, but have not been able to do so using the `ComPtr` member functions or the interface member functions.

Can someone help?

Comment: your factory pointer points to nothing. And there is no `wicBitmap` anywhere in that code, so &wicBitmap point to 0x00000000 doesn't make any sense regardless. You need a factory first, which can be created with simple CoCreateInstance. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-api), where you will find an example in the middle of the page.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/wic/-wic-creating-encoder.md

Answer (score -1):

Are you using ScreenGrab in the DTK12?

If so and you want to use the CreateEncoder function in ScreenGrab... In the SaveWICTextureToFile function

/* These includes and libraries must be accessible to ScreenGrab.h and ScreenGrab.cpp */

```
#include <guided.h>
#include <uuid.h>
#include <d3d12.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "uuid.lib"
#include <wincodec.h>
 #pragma comment(lib, "Windowscodecs.lib)
```

The fileName must be a

```
const wchar_t* fileName
```

(With correct path) and the file extension must match (example .png)

```
REFGUID guidContainerFormat = GUID_ContainerFormatPng;
const GUID* targetFormat = (const GUID*)NULL;

ComPtr<IWICBitmapEncoder> encoder;
HRESULT hr = pWIC->CreateEncoder(guidContainerFormat, targetFormat, encoder.GetAddressOf);
'''
Works!
```